# Looping multiple ids into variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I've been creating a code on our Sharepoint page, which takes the selected items in a list and takes a specific field which contains email and open it in a email client. However at the moment it only takes the first object which you can see by the `[0]` in the variable `selectedItemId`. I'm then trying to create a loop so i can all the objects instead of just the first as you can see below. However the loop does not seem to work and it returns following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

How can i create such a loop?

**Retrieving the first object only (working):**

```
function GetSelectedItemsID() {

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

var listGuid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()
//in this example only first selected item is retrieved



var selectedItemId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()[0].id
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
var list = lists.getById(listGuid);
var item = list.getItemById(selectedItemId);
ctx.load(item);


ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var title = item.get_item("E_x002d_Mail_x0020_1");
    var email = "mailto:" + title + ";";
    window.location.href = email;
}, function(){alert("error");});

});



}
```

**What i've tried (doesnt work)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function GetSelectedItemsID() {

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

var listGuid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
//in this example only first selected item is retrieved

    var allSelectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
    var item;
    var ItemEmails='';


    for (item in allSelectedItems){

        var selectedItemId = allSelectedItems[item].id;
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        var lists = web.get_lists();
        var list = lists.getById(listGuid);
        var item = list.getItemById(selectedItemId);
        ctx.load(item);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var title = item.get_item("E_x002d_Mail_x0020_1");
        ItemEmails += "mailto:" + title + ";";

        }, function(){alert("error");

        });

        window.location.href = ItemEmails;
    }

}

}
</script>
```

Comment: You have an extra `});` after your `ctx.executeQueryAsync`

Comment: doesnt make any difference. the code still does not work

Comment: Well, that's the reason for the syntax error, which you really should have spotted yourself. Do check what the new error is and include the line number this time.

Comment: You're correct i should have spotted that myself! however all i'm getting is following errors: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: GetSelectedItemsID is not defined`